# Magento shopping cart price rule in EE 1.14

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, enterprise

I am working on magento shop having Enterprise 1.14, In my old shop which is based on magento CE 1.81, there is shopping cart price rule to buy x items and get y free.

After up gradation to EE 1.14, this rule applies only on first item of cart out of z items meeting the criteria. In my rule definition I have set **stop further processing** to **Yes** and rule's priority is 0 which mean this rule should run on each item of cart and stop to affect any other rule but it works only first item of cart and then nothing.

When I dig into code, I saw they have below code in foreach loop at line 317 of `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` model.

```
if ($this->_stopFurtherRules) {
            break;
        }
```

In release notes of magento CE 1.9 and EE 1.14, they have mentioned that

**The setting Stop Further Rules Processing is honored.**

so my question is, what does mean of **The setting Stop Further Rules Processing is honored.** ?

Have they changed the meaning of **Stop Further Rules Processing** or is it bug in magnto CE 1.9 and EE 1.14?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have

"Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To" set to "1"

This is what tells Magento how many times it's allowed to process this rule".

Let me know what this is set to and I will be glad to help from there.